# I want to make categories page for the shopping application in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have made the categories page for my project by making categories page and the data which I am going to display in the category page is imported from data.dart file and I have to use the visible widget but I am facing an error using the code.

The code of data.dart is below:

```
List<Category> categories = [
  Category(
    name: 'Accessories',
    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.tshirt,
  ),
  Category(
    name: 'AutoMobiles',
    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.car,
  ),
  Category(
    name: 'Beauty and Health',
    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.hatCowboy,
  ),
  Category(
    name: 'Business & Industrial',
    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.cashRegister,
  ),
  Category(
    name: 'Book and Learning',
    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.book,
  ),
  Category(
    name: 'Computer and Peripherals ',
    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.laptop,
  ),
  Category(
    name: 'Electronics ',
    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.tv,
  ),
```

and the code for making the categories page is given below:

```
class CategoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'categoryPage';

  @override
  _CategoryPageState createState() => _CategoryPageState();
}

class _CategoryPageState extends State<CategoryPage> {
  bool isClicked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              'All Categories',
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: categories.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                isClicked = !isClicked;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Icon(
                              categories[index].icon,
                            ),
                          ),
                          title: Visibility(
                            visible: isClicked,
                            child: Text(
                              categories[index].name,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: 1,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                leading: Text('Hello!'),
                              );
                            }),
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        //   bottomNavigationBar: NavBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have researched well but am unable to solve the problem. How can I get the desirable output and the image file which I was trying to make in the categories page like the image attached below?

[image]

Comment: please send the error text

Comment: here is the error text: I/flutter ( 7097): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 7097): RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

A `Column` will always try to `shrinkWrap` it's children, using Expanded means the child is supposed to occupy the entire height, these two are mutually exclusive.

A better way to use a Single Scroll View without all those Expanded widgets would be this.

```
class CategoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'categoryPage';

  @override
  _CategoryPageState createState() => _CategoryPageState();
}

class _CategoryPageState extends State<CategoryPage> {
  bool isClicked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                'All Categories',
              ),
              ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: categories.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                isClicked = !isClicked;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Icon(
                              categories[index].icon,
                            ),
                          ),
                          title: Visibility(
                            visible: isClicked,
                            child: Text(
                              categories[index].name,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: 1,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                leading: Text('Hello!'),
                              );
                            }),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        //   bottomNavigationBar: NavBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If the Error is caused by the Inner ListView, you can apply the same logic of `SingleChildScrollView()`